# Add a filter to an add page in django admin

Tags: django-admin, django-admin-filters

Within my site, there is a model that contains two fields, pattern and group.
I am trying to have a search within the add function for the model. The reason is that there are over 1000 patterns, and having them all in a select isn't very user friendly. I would like for the user to be able to enter a pattern, then have the user select from the patterns matching their search. Is there any way that I could do this?

Comment: for example, Within the default admin page if you go to add group, you can filter the permissions

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, just for the pattern